# Anaconda missing matplotlib

Tags: python, anaconda

```
G:\Git\advsol\projects\autotune>conda env create -f env.yml -n auto-tune
Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata .................

ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - matplotlib 2.1.1 py35_0


G:\Git\advsol\projects\autotune>
```

I have tried "conda install matplotlib==2.1.1"
it doesn't work

this is the env.yml file

```
name: auto-tune
channels:
- menpo
- conda-forge
- defaults
dependencies:
- backports=1.0=py35_1
- backports.functools_lru_cache=1.4=py35_1
- boost-cpp=1.64.0=vc14_1
- ca-certificates=2017.7.27.1=0
- certifi=2017.7.27.1=py35_0
- cloudpickle=0.4.0=py35_0
- colorama=0.3.9=py35_0
- cycler=0.10.0=py35_0
- dask-core=0.16.0=py_0
- decorator=4.1.2=py35_0
- eigen=3.3.3=0
- expat=2.2.5=vc14_0
- freetype=2.7=vc14_2
- future=0.16.0=py35_0
- icu=58.1=vc14_1
- imageio=2.2.0=py35_0
- ipykernel=4.6.1=py35_0
- ipyparallel=6.0.2=py35_0
- ipython=6.2.1=py35_0
- ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py35_0
- jedi=0.10.2=py35_0
- jpeg=9b=vc14_2
- jupyter_client=5.2.2=py35_0
- jupyter_core=4.4.0=py_0
- libiconv=1.14=vc14_4
- libpng=1.6.28=vc14_2
- libsodium=1.0.15=vc14_1
- libtiff=4.0.7=vc14_1
- libxml2=2.9.5=vc14_1
- matplotlib=2.1.1=py35_0
- mayavi=4.5.0=np111py35_vc14_1
- networkx=1.11=py35_0
- nlopt=2.4.2=py35_vc14_2
- olefile=0.44=py35_0
- openssl=1.0.2l=vc14_0
- pagmo=2.4=vc14_1
- pickleshare=0.7.4=py35_0
- pillow=4.3.0=py35_1
- prompt_toolkit=1.0.15=py35_0
- pygments=2.2.0=py35_0
- pygmo=2.4=np111py35_0
- pyparsing=2.2.0=py35_0
- pyqt=5.6.0=py35_4
- python=3.5.4=0
- python-dateutil=2.6.1=py35_0
- pytz=2017.3=py_2
- pywavelets=0.5.2=py35_1
- pyzmq=16.0.2=py35_3
- qt=5.6.2=vc14_1
- scikit-image=0.13.0=py35_3
- setuptools=36.6.0=py35_1
- simplegeneric=0.8.1=py35_0
- sip=4.18=py35_1
- six=1.11.0=py35_1
- sqlite=3.20.1=vc14_2
- tbb=2018_20170919=vc14_0
- tk=8.5.19=vc14_1
- toolz=0.8.2=py_2
- tornado=4.5.2=py35_0
- traitlets=4.3.2=py35_0
- traits=4.6.0=py35_1
- vc=14=0
- vs2015_runtime=14.0.25420=0
- vtk=7.1.0=py35_vc14_4
- wcwidth=0.1.7=py35_0
- wheel=0.30.0=py35_2
- win_unicode_console=0.5=py35_0
- wincertstore=0.2=py35_0
- yaml=0.1.7=vc14_0
- zeromq=4.2.3=vc14_2
- zlib=1.2.11=vc14_0
- configobj=5.0.6=py35_0
- icc_rt=2017.0.4=h97af966_0
- intel-openmp=2018.0.0=hcd89f80_7
- mkl=2018.0.0=h36b65af_4
- numpy=1.11.3=py35h4fc39be_3
- pip=9.0.1=py35_0
- scikit-learn=0.19.1=py35h2037775_0
- scipy=1.0.0=py35h75710e8_0
- apptools=4.4.0=py35_0
- boost=1.63.0=py35_vc14_2
- envisage=4.5.1=py35_0
- opencv3=3.1.0=py35_0
- pyface=5.1.0=py35_0
- traitsui=5.1.0=py35_0
- pip:
  - absl-py==0.1.7
  - backports.functools-lru-cache==1.4
  - bleach==1.5.0
  - colour-demosaicing==0.1.2
  - colour-science==0.3.10
  - dask==0.16.0
  - entrypoints==0.2.3
  - exifread==2.1.2
  - gast==0.2.0
  - html5lib==0.9999999
  - ipython-genutils==0.2.0
  - ipywidgets==7.1.1
  - jinja2==2.10
  - jsonschema==2.6.0
  - jupyter==1.0.0
  - jupyter-client==5.2.2
  - jupyter-console==5.2.0
  - jupyter-core==4.4.0
  - markdown==2.6.10
  - markupsafe==1.0
  - mistune==0.8.3
  - nbconvert==5.3.1
  - nbformat==4.4.0
  - nose==1.3.7
  - notebook==5.4.0
  - pandocfilters==1.4.2
  - prompt-toolkit==1.0.15
  - protobuf==3.5.1
  - pywinpty==0.5.1
  - qtconsole==4.3.1
  - rawpy==0.10.1
  - send2trash==1.4.2
  - tb-nightly==1.5.0a20180102
  - terminado==0.8.1
  - testpath==0.3.1
  - tf-nightly==1.5.0.dev20180102
  - werkzeug==0.14.1
  - widgetsnbextension==3.1.3
  - win-unicode-console==0.5
prefix: G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3_501\envs\auto-tune
```

**Update I tried conda install matplotlib=2.1.1**

```
G:\Git\advsol\projects\autotune>conda install matplotlib=2.1.1
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    blas:                   1.0-mkl
    conda-package-handling: 1.3.11-py36_0
    libarchive:             3.3.3-h798a506_1
    lz4-c:                  1.8.1.2-h2fa13f4_0
    python-libarchive-c:    2.8-py36_11
    tqdm:                   4.32.1-py_0
    xz:                     5.2.4-h2fa13f4_4
    zstd:                   1.3.3-hfe6a214_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    conda:                  4.3.30-py36h7e176b0_0 --> 4.7.10-py36_0
    conda-env:              2.6.0-h36134e3_1      --> 2.6.0-1
    libxml2:                2.9.4-vc14h8fd0f11_5  --> 2.9.8-hadb2253_1
    matplotlib:             2.1.0-py36h11b4b9c_0  --> 2.1.1-py36h2062329_0
    menuinst:               1.4.10-py36h42196fb_0 --> 1.4.14-py36hfa6e2cd_0
    openssl:                1.0.2l-vc14hcac20b0_2 --> 1.0.2p-hfa6e2cd_0
    pycosat:                0.6.2-py36hf17546d_1  --> 0.6.3-py36hfa6e2cd_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

menuinst-1.4.1 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00  11.74 MB/s
blas-1.0-mkl.t 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   1.55 MB/s
conda-env-2.6. 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 938.32 kB/s
lz4-c-1.8.1.2- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00  18.51 MB/s
openssl-1.0.2p 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00  34.74 MB/s
xz-5.2.4-h2fa1 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00  16.77 MB/s
libxml2-2.9.8- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00  28.75 MB/s
pycosat-0.6.3- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00  16.66 MB/s
tqdm-4.32.1-py 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00  11.74 MB/s
zstd-1.3.3-hfe 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00  20.92 MB/s
libarchive-3.3 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00  22.73 MB/s
python-libarch 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   7.77 MB/s
conda-package- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00  28.76 MB/s
matplotlib-2.1 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00  29.00 MB/s
conda-4.7.10-p 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00  27.90 MB/s
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::tqdm-4.32.1-py_0'.
CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.
Attempting to roll back.


CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.
```

Comment: Use a single equal sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 
`conda install matplotlib=2.1.1`

Comment: it gives the same output as with ==

Comment: @Gilad try running `conda clean --packages` is what Conda suggests

Answer (score 0):

create  a new environment and try the below commands

```
conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib
```

or

```
 conda install matplotlib
```